# Visual Studio 2013/2015 Test Project Template - for NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, visual-studio-2015, project-template

I'm new to unit testing and started with MSTest and want to use NUnit.  I see there is a Test project template in VS 2015 but I read that for NUnit I'm to create a class library then add the NUnit NuGet packages.

What is correct? Test Project Template or Class Library for NUnit in C#?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test project sets up a project where you can test from within Visual Studio. NUnit tests are done externally. They are different options, each with different requirements.

If you want to do NUnit follow the NUnit instructions, create a class library then add the NUnit packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is no NUnit test project template in Visual Stusio that comes out of the box.

A test project is a class library with a reference to nunit.framework.dll that comes with NUnit installation.

You can create your own NUnit project template in Visual Studio:

1. Creating a new class library
2. Reference nunit.framework.dll
3. Create test.cs file

   - Add "using NUnit.Framework;"
   - Create an empty test class and a test method (you can also add setup and teardown to the test class)

Your Test.cs File should look something like this:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class SuccessTests
  {
    [SetUp] public void Init()
    { /* ... */ }

    [TearDown] public void Dispose()
    { /* ... */ }

    [Test] public void Test1()
    { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

4. Use [Export Template wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) to create a template out of your project.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2015 you have the [Create Unit Test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/03/06/creating-unit-test-stubs.aspx) functionality,right click your method and choose test framework.  If you install the [NUnit extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd30bf3f-4183-4b00-a245-1875316b8cd3) for this, it will create the test project - as a Test Project, add the nuget package and create a test class with an empty test method for you to fill out.  It is not TDD all the way, but if you already have the method it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

The NUnit team has now created [Visual Studio Templates for NUnit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cd55f79-4936-49e7-b81d-c40fcd81abc7). Just install the extension in Visual Studio and you will find NUnit test projects for various platforms.